# BIND9 DNS Problems - Not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, resolve, nameserver

I host a BIND9 DNS server for my VirtualMin users to use. And It only resolves for 75% of the people. It has been WELL over 1 week now.

Here is a sample.

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA axxim.net. root.axxim.net. (
            1274031391
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
@   IN  NS  axxim.net.
day7tech.com.   IN  A   96.226.216.37
www.day7tech.com.   IN  A   96.226.216.37
ftp.day7tech.com.   IN  A   96.226.216.37
m.day7tech.com. IN  A   96.226.216.37
localhost.day7tech.com. IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.day7tech.com.   IN  A   96.226.216.37
admin.day7tech.com. IN  A   96.226.216.37
mail.day7tech.com.  IN  A   96.226.216.37
day7tech.com.   IN  MX  5 mail.day7tech.com.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
@   IN  NS  axxim.net.
```

With this:

```
@   IN  NS  ns1.axxim.net.
@   IN  NS  ns2.axxim.net.
ns1 IN  A   96.226.216.37
ns2 IN  A   96.226.216.37
```

and then go find someone else to provide secondary DNS service for you, so you can change `ns2`'s IP address to something offsite.

Comment: Thanks so much! 
Could I use a service like Afraid.org for Backup DNS?

Comment: they offer “free backup DNS”, so it looks like it. honestly, though — a good DNS setup makes a difference; it’s worth not skimping too much if you can help it.

Answer (score 2):

The stub records in the `net` TLD state that your nameservers are `ns1.axxim.net` and `ns2.axxim.net` — this is what resolving nameservers will look at to find out who to ask for records for your domain.

`ns1.axxim.net` doesn’t exist.

`ns2.axxim.net` has the same IP as you have listed for `ns.axxim.net`.

You need to adjust your domain to match the stubs (i.e., replace `ns.axxim.net` with `ns1` and `ns2`), and make sure both servers are serving the domain properly.

Comment: Would I need to do this at BIND9 or my domain provider for axxim.net?

Comment: what do you mean by your “domain provider”? If you’re writing zonefiles, surely *you’re* the domain provider? What is `ns2.axxim.net` supposed to be — do you have a secondary DNS provider or another server running as a slave? What did you specify `ns2.axxim.net` as being when you registered the domain?

Comment: Most Domain Registrars require 2 name servers. I don't have 2. I only have 1. I don't have a backup dns server.